# cannot access public members of class extending JPanel

Tags: java, swing, public

Here is my class

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class NewOrLoadPanel extends JPanel {
    public DefaultComboBoxModel<String> usernameChoiceList;
    public JRadioButton newCloset = new JRadioButton();
    public JRadioButton loadCloset = new JRadioButton();
    public JButton next;
    public JComboBox usernameChoice;
    ButtonGroup newOrLoad = new ButtonGroup();

    public NewOrLoadPanel(XMLParsed choices) {
        initComponents(choices);
    }

    private void initComponents(XMLParsed choices) {

        newCloset.setText("New Closet File");
        newCloset.setActionCommand("new");
        loadCloset.setText("Load Closet from File...");
        loadCloset.setActionCommand("load");
        newOrLoad.add(newCloset);
        newOrLoad.add(loadCloset);
        next = new JButton("Next");
        add(loadCloset);
        add(newCloset);
        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Choose a username from the list below: ");
        add(inputLabel);

        usernameChoiceList = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : choices.hexUsernameMap.entrySet()) {
            usernameChoiceList.addElement(mapEntry.getKey());
        }
        usernameChoice = new JComboBox(usernameChoiceList);
        add(usernameChoice);

    }
    public String getSelectedAction() {
        return newOrLoad.getSelection().getActionCommand();
    }
}
```

I'm using the following code to create it and I am *trying* to access the user input from the panel components.

```java
private void newOrLoadChooser() {
        hexUserObject = new XMLParsed();
        JPanel dialogPanel = new NewOrLoadPanel(hexUserObject);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, dialogPanel, "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        boolean userChoice = dialogPanel.getComponent(1).isFocusOwner();
        if (userChoice == true) { // new file
            newClosetChooser();
            myInv = new ParsedInventory(hexValue, username);
            validateFolders(myInv.getUsername());
        }
        else {
            myInv = loadInventoryFile();
            validateFolders(myInv.getUsername());

        }

    }
```

note: some of these variables have global scope in the class calling this function. So the code compiles and runs, and shows the dialog etc.

I'm trying to make `userChoice` reflect the radio button selection. However, I cannot access the radio buttons directly via `dialogPanel.newCloset` or `dialogPanel.loadCloset` as it tells me it does not exist.

So I tried making the button group a public attribute, too. And tried retrieving the String using `dialogPanel.newOrLoad.getSelection().getActionCommand()` but that also was acting like it didn't exist.

So I tried making that getter for the `getActionCommand()` as above and it can't find that public function either.

I have other classes that extend JPanel that have accessible public attributes. I don't get what's wrong here. All I can think is that the dialogPanel is getting destroyed when the dialog closes, except in my debugger it's still showing all the components existing. And well, if it is the case that those things aren't persisting.. how do I fix this? I'd prefer not to build the panel inside my function as I want to keep things clean.

Comment: Since there is no reason for extending a `JPanel` obvious in the code above, my suggestion is **don't** extend here, just use an instance of a plain `JPanel`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson my reason for extending it was to bring all the setup code out of that function and keep the code cleaner/more compartmentalized. Isn't that generally best practice?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `NewOrLoadPanel` type directly instead of `JPanel`:

```java
NewOrLoadPanel dialogPanel = new NewOrLoadPanel(hexUserObject);

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, dialogPanel, "", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
boolean isLoadCloset = dialogPanel.loadCloset.isSelected();
boolean isNewCloset = dialogPanel.newCloset.isSelected();
```

Comment: That's a good catch. Unfortunately it doesn't fix my issue.